# Grammar and semantics

Tags: grammar, sentence, semantics, writing-advice

Is the following sentence grammatically and semantically right?

> "Despite what was in the past, nowadays extended family is an integral part of our lives"

Comment: I think the sentence could better be rephrased as— _Extended families are an integral part of our lives nowadays, as opposed to the past._

Comment: _Despite_ (or, better still) _unlike how it was in the past..._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reformulation may be a bit more complicated, but it does convey your meaning:

> Though it may not be the case in the past, nowadays extended family *(I would put family in the plural - ***extended families***)*  are an integral part of our lives.

I also liked Kate's suggestion with ***unlike*** because it offers a more concise possibility:

> Unlike in the past, nowadays extended families are an integral part of our lives.

Comment: _unlike **in** the past_?

Comment: I think so. Without 'unlike' the sentence would read _In the past extended families were an integral part of our lives._

Comment: Why not simply omit _in_? The sentence reads better without it. Keeping it seems to affect the parallelism of the sentence as well. If one wishes to retain _in_, rephrasing the sentence is called for— _Unlike in the past, extended families are an integral part of our lives in the present._

Comment: yes, you could reformulate it in this way. But if you put 'in the present' at the end, it loses the emphasis the meaning had in the original sentence

Comment: The PP could be tacked anywhere; that's no issue.